# Display Sinatra Basic HTTP Auth On One Page Only

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Any idea how I can make Sinatra HTTP auth display only on one page in a modular Sinatra application?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please [be unambiguous, and add details and context, as mentioned in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), so that other users are able to help you effectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding to @iain answer, since you have asked HTTP Auth(I am assuming Basic auth).

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  def authorized?
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    @auth.provided? && @auth.basic? && @auth.credentials && @auth.credentials == ["CUSTOM_USERNAME","SECRET_PASSWORD"]
  end

  def protected!
    unless authorized?
      response['WWW-Authenticate'] = %(Basic realm="Restricted Area")
      throw(:halt, [401, "Oops... we need your login name & password\n"])
    end
  end

  get "/protected_content" do
    protected!
    "in secure"
  end

  get "/" do
    "anyone can access"
  end
end
```

Comment: Good stuff, +1. I'd also recommend changing `["CUSTOM_USERNAME","SECRET_PASSWORD"]` to `[ENV["CUSTOM_USERNAME"],ENV["SECRET_PASSWORD"]]` and loading them into the server's environment so that passwords aren't passed around in the code and via source control etc.

Comment: I actually altered code to hard coded value to make it simple. It makes more sense to mention it :).

Answer (score 3):

The comment by Vicky Chijwani is correct, you should give a lot more info (take note!) but here's an answer.

You could do it several ways. If we assume your authentication method is called `protected!`:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base # assumed for all examples

  get "/only-this-page-has-auth" do
    protected!
    "Only admin allowed!"
  end

  get "/this-wont-have-auth" do
    "Everybody can access this"
  end
end
```

Or you could use [a filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters)

```
  before "/only-this-page-has-auth" do
    protected!
  end

  get "/only-this-page-has-auth" do
    "Only admin allowed!"
  end

  get "/this-wont-have-auth" do
    "Everybody can access this"
  end
```

Or if you're going to use `Sinatra::Namespace` from the [sinatra-contrib gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-contrib) (maybe a bit more of an advanced usage, but I use this a lot as I find it a nice way to do things) and the protected page would now be at "/admin/only-this-page-has-auth"

```
  namespace "/admin" do
    before do
      protected!
    end
    get "/only-this-page-has-auth" do
      "Only admin allowed!"
    end
  end

  get "/this-wont-have-auth" do
    "Everybody can access this"
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use:
https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-basic-auth
The documentation is great:

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/basic_auth"

# Specify your authorization logic
authorize do |username, password|
  username == "john" && password == "doe"
end

# Set protected routes
protect do
  get "/admin" do
    "Restricted page that only admin can access"
  end
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-basic-auth/0.1.0
It's really simple to use